# Не отображаются буквы в pygame

Tags: python-3.x, шрифты, pygame

Добавил буквы к игре все работает, сделал сцену паузы, а в ней не отображаются кнопки, но работают, можно угадать где они расположены и нажать, и все сработает как надо, вот только текст не видно, пробовал фон закрашивать, не закрашивать. Вот код

```
class Menu():
    def __init__(self, punkts = [120, 140, u'Punkt', active, disable, 0]):
        self.punkts = punkts
    def render(self, num_punkt):
        for i in self.punkts:
            if num_punkt == i[5]:
                menu.blit(fontword.render(i[2], 1, i[4]), (i[0], i[1]))
            else:
                menu.blit(fontword.render(i[2], 1, i[3]), (i[0], i[1]))
    def menu(self):
        done = True
        putkt = 0
        while done:
            game.fill(whitegray)
            menu.blit(game, (0, 0))
            self.mp = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for i in self.punkts:
                if self.mp[0] > i[0] and self.mp[0] < i[0] + 155 and self.mp[1] > i[1] and self.mp[1] < i[1] + 50:
                    putkt = i[5]
            self.render(putkt)
            for e in pygame.event.get():
                if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        sys.exit()
                    if e.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        if putkt > 0:
                            putkt -= 1
                    if e.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        if putkt < len(self.punkts) - 1:
                            putkt += 1
                if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and e.button:
                    if putkt == 0:
                        done = False
                    elif putkt == 2:
                        sys.exit()
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Теперь поясню что к чему: 
punkts - элементы пункта, 
fontword - шрифт для букв (стандартный пока что), 
game - Surface игры основной, 
menu - Surface для меню. 
А еще хотелось бы чтобы фон просто заблюрился и элементы были видны

Comment: Вы скиньте кусок рабочего кода чтобы - бы можно было запустить и посмотреть , а так придётся заново воспроизводить  то что вы показали код ровным счётом не о чём не говорит имейте ввиду что питон ОПП язык и на нём можно такую писанину развести....

Comment: Может весь код кинуть чтобы наверняка? Заодно может решится проблема с InputBox на Tkinter, который не закрывается. [ссылка](http://rgho.st/6MQxMpsYr)

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что вы  супер умный а люди которые разрабытывают язык Python так делать нечего ?

Comment: Не, я хочу сказать что я недавно с Python познакомился и не понимаю еще его, хотел бы чтобы вы объяснили что я не так сделал в коде?

Comment: Да скиньте весь код я запущу и скажу в чём проблема

Comment: http://rgho.st/6MQxMpsYr